# accessing private member from virtual funciton without making all class friends

Tags: c++, c++11

regarding code below I want that Other::second_function() has access to HavePrivateMember::set_member

```
class HavePrivateMember {
private:
  int _m_member;
  void set_member(int val) { _m_member = val; }
};

class OtherBase {
};
class Other : public OtherBase {
   virtual void first_function(); // no access for you
   virtual void second_function(); // want access to HavePrivateMember::set_member
}
```

I thought about defining a class inside Other::second_function() and update HavePrivateMember  with friend declaration, but it doesn't identify "friend class PenetratingClass;" below

```
class HavePrivateMember {
friend class PenetratingClass;
private:
  int _m_member;
  void set_member(int val) { member = val; }
};

class Other : public OtherBase {

   virtual void second_function() {
      HavePrivateMember has_private_obj;

       class PenetratingClass {
         public:
          void penetrate(HavePrivateMember& has_private_obj) {
             has_private_obj.set_member(5);
          }
       };
       PenetratingClass my_penet;
       my_penet.penetrate(has_private_obj);
   }
}
```

I get

```
error: void HavePrivateMember::set_member(int) is private
```

Comment: What's `cPacketTerm`, and how, if at all, is it related to `HavePrivateMember` or any other classes that appear in your code?

Comment: The made-up class names make the shown code hard to grok, but, in general, no third class should be needed. `OtherBase` is the `friend`, with a `protected` method that accesses `HavePrivateMember`, so that all subclasses can invoke.

Comment: fixed my code, sorry for that

Comment: `friend class PenetratingClass;` implicitly declares a class named `PenetratingClass` at file scope, as if you had `class PenetratingClass;` immediately following the closing brace of `HavePrivateMember` definition. The local class `PenetratingClass` defined within the function is an entirely different class that just happens to have the same name; it was not declared a friend.

Comment: The error shown cannot possibly be produced by the code shown. It complains that `set_member` is protected, but in the code it's private.

Comment: Hi Sam, I want only the second_funciton in the derived class to have access to set_member not OtherBase class and not the Other class

Comment: Hi Igor, Yes that's the issue what is the full scope name of the PenetratingClass  defined above? I want to define it inside HavePrivateMember

Comment: You can write `friend void Other::second_function();` in `HavePrivateMember`. You will of course have to arrange class definitions so that `Other::second_function` is declared before `HavePrivateMember`

Comment: Well, you can define a class inside `HavePrivateMember` that has access to the private member, and exposes it to its callers. But at that point you could just as well make the member public to begin with, as anyone can access it anyway via that proxy class. Frankly, I suspect an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), as the goal you are purportedly trying to achieve doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi Igor,it was my misunderstanding. I thought only static funciton can be defined as friends to class

Comment: This sounds like a design error; you can't fix it with code. A base class defines two interfaces: one for outsiders and one for derived classes. The question is about how to make a **single** class define **three different** interfaces: one for outsiders and **two** for derived classes. Either the base class is doing too many things or this is just over-designed.